# Re-connect Exchange to domain

Tags: exchange-2010

My company are using DC ( 2008R2 ) and Exchange 2010. I purchased another server ( Windows 2012 R2 ) and I will transfer master domain controller from old server ( 2008R2 ) to new server. What should I do to connect current Exchange server to new master DC ?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad stroke question. There are any number of considerations you might want to take depending on what your setup looks like.

All servers and clients will connect to any available DC depending on what they are doing. Assuming you have moved FSMO-roles over to the new DC, and you set it as the new primary DNS server, most communication will start being routed to it.

Comment: The schedule to setup new server is next 2 week.

What information you need about my configuration ?

Assuming all DC function will work normaly after migrating to new master DC server  and I'm concenr about Exchange Server.

As far as I know that Exchange server use DNS / LDAP and some information from DC. So what will happend when DC is moved to new server ( with different server name and ip address ) Does it automatically route to new master DC , doesn' it ?

I'm sorry If I don't explain clearly because English is not my primary language but I will try explain as much as I can>

Comment: If you are planning to keep the old server as well as the new one, you don't need to do much else than to join the new server to the AD and promote it to a DC. If not, I think the full procedure is too long to explain all in here, but there is alot to google on it. Also look at JohnSmith's post regarding the DHCP which goes a bit deeper into explaining what I meant about the DNS-service. When the new server is up and running you can transfer the FSMO-roles, making it the primary DC. After everything is synced, the Exchange server will be able to get same info from the new server as the old one

Answer (score 0):

You would load your new 2012 R2 server up and connect it to the domain and then promote it to a domain controller.  Give the new server a few days to ensure that syncing is OK (checkout [dcdiag command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc731968.aspx)).  At that point the new Domain controller will have all the information your Exchange environment needs.  Some other things you may need to worry about is adjusting your DNS settings.  Domain controllers in small environments are typically also a DNS server so you'll need to update all servers with static IP's to you the new server as a DNS server.  Also if it's a DHCP server you'll want to remember to update it settings to give your clients the new DNS server/Domain Controller ip address as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

@JohnSmith: Do you mean I have nothing to do to re-config Exchange server in order connecting to new master domain controller ? Will it connect to new master DC automatically , won't it ?